# python urllib and fetch

Tags: python

I would like to use `urllib2` to request the content of a page like this one:

http://www.google.com/key?=AqIkNRT0ZoH2c5E6u4Lu&access=lawrence

My Python code so far:

```
for key in keysfile.readlines(): 
  host="http://www.google.com/key?=%s&access=%s"%(key,access)
  reg = urllib2.Request(host)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(reg)
  check = response.read()
  print(check)
```

but problems have happened and I think there is something wrong.

Comment: Which problem? Which error do you get?

Comment: you could use the requests lib.

Comment: It seems `?` and `key` are swapped in the url. In general, you should urlencode the query part e.g., `url = 'http://example.com/?' +  urlencode(dict(key=key, access=access))`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a tutorial on this subject over a year ago:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/

You can use urllib or the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package.

Here are a couple examples:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/wxDbViewer.zip'

print "downloading with urllib"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "code.zip")

print "downloading with urllib2"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("code2.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)

print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("code3.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: You could use `shutil.copyfileobj(f, code)` to avoid loading (potentially large file into memory).

Comment: Yeah...or you could use a loop and read a few bytes at a time until it's completely downloaded.